# Relationship to Composite Foreign Key on Single Column

Tags: sql, database-design, database-schema, relationship

I've added a 'version' column to a table that needs to be part of the table's primary key, but I've got a foreign key relationships to tables that don't contain the version. (And shouldn't) I'm sure I'm going to get at least one answer explaining why this isn't possible, I get why I can't create a relationship here. I'm looking for an elegent/painless way around it. The behavior I need is that the main table can add versions while the 'other table' remains linked to all of them. This is effectively a many-to-many relationship without a join table. (However in practice only one 'version' of the main table for a given key is active at any given time.) I plan to enforce my own referencial integrity using a mix of check constraints and triggers...but is there a better way? Thanks

**TABLE**

```
TableID (uniqueidentifier) - PRIMARY KEY
Version (int) - PRIMARY KEY
...
```

**OTHERTABLE**

```
OtherTableID (int) - PRIMARY KEY
TableID (uniqueidentifier)
...
```

Comment: If you don't need the `Version` in other tables, don't make it part of the Primary Key of the parent table.

Comment: Then I'd have duplicate `TableIDs` in the main table...

Comment: Should other tables have an FK to a specific version?

Comment: No, the version doesn't matter to the othertable's relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be better to split `TABLE` into two tables: one with the data that never change (which may just be the ID itself) and one with the data that need to be versioned. `OTHERTABLE` will have a foreign key to the first one.

(I should mention that we've used this approach where I work, and it's sometimes caused annoying complications, especially when we've wanted to change our minds about which fields need to be versioned. It's really not perfect. But other approaches tend to result in even *bigger* problems.)

Comment: +1 - Now that I think about it I'm using this approch in another application as well. In this case this is basically just a link table...I'll see if this has any other implications for this particular DB.

Comment: Implemented, works beautifully. Only required a single line of code added to the application to handle inserts into the main table.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your specs:

```
Parent
======
ParentID (uniqueidentifier) - PRIMARY KEY
...


OtherTable
==========
OtherTableID (int) - PRIMARY KEY
ParentID (int) -  FOREIGN KEY
...

ParentVersion
=============
ParentID (int) - PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY
Version (int) - PRIMARY KEY
```

And if you want an active version per Parent, one more table:

```
ParentActiveVersion
=============
ParentID (int) - PRIMARY KEY 
Version (int) 
FOREIGN KEY (ParentID, Version)
  REFERENCES ParentVersion(ParentID, Version)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Following is valid for SQL Server.  I make no claims about other RDBMS.*

Don't make it part of the PK, just add a `UNIQUE INDEX` on those two fields to enforce uniqueness:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_MyIndexName ON TABLE(TableID, Version)`

You won't need to touch existing keys but it'll keep duplicate values out of the table.

If you decide down the road that you want to reference both these fields at once (and you are using SQL Server), then you can use a unique index as a target for a foreign key as well if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly kludgy, but anything here will be - based on @ypercube's comment - could the other tables not all be built to reference version 1 (using a computed column to force the 1 to appear in a column in each of those tables)